# Is it possible to use OR and LIKE keyword together in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring data JPA. In my scenario I'm trying to use both OR and LIKE keyword together to search some data from database like

`findByFirstnameLikeOrLastnameLike`

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah I've tried and it's working. Thanks for replying